# React UseEffect unmounted component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

I get the following error: "*Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.*"

And my useEffect hook looks like this using axios:

```
const isMounted = useRef(false);
useEffect(() => {
isMounted.current = true;
    getSomething(new URLSearchParams(props.location.search), cancelToken).then((response: any) => {
      const res = response.data;
      if(isMounted.current) setState(res);
    });
    return () => {
      isMounted.current = false;
      if(!isMounted.current) cancelToken.cancel();
    }
  }, [props.location.search]);
```

Where do I have a memory leak? I am able to render my component without the axios return statement, but I still get the memory leak warning.

Comment: I am unsure why your approach isn't working, but sometimes I have had to resort to using something like the hook described here: https://gist.github.com/jaydenseric/a67cfb1b809b1b789daa17dfe6f83daa#gistcomment-3356735
You would then check if isMounted is true before calling setState

Comment: Where is this hook located exactly?

Comment: This code doesn't represent the problem, please make a reproducible example [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Edited using "useRef"

Answer (score 0):

Json fetching example using axios wrapper ([Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/use-async-effect-axios-demo-forked-p8mqi?file=/src/TestComponent.js))

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useAsyncEffect } from "use-async-effect2";
import cpAxios from "cp-axios";

export default function TestComponent(props) {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  useAsyncEffect(
    function* () {
      setText("fetching...");
      const response = yield cpAxios(props.url); // cancellable request
      setText(`Success: ${JSON.stringify(response.data)}`);
    },
    [props.url]
  );

  return <div>{text}</div>;
}
```